# Stack not pushing items into the collection

Tags: java, stack

My implementation of the collection is as follows:

```
    private void init(Node<K, E> root) {
        Node<K,E> node = root;

        while (node != null) {
            stack.push(node);
            node = node.getLeft();
        }
    }
```

However when it gets invoked and used, it seems that there is nothing in the Stack. I've tried debugging exhaustively without any avail, any suggestions as to what might be going wrong in the way I implemented the above components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made your `Stack`s immutable.  When you call the `push()` method, it doesn't actually push the node on to the stack, it returns a new immutable `Stack` with that element pushed on to it.  When calling all modifying methods such as `push` and `pop`, prepend `stack =` on the line to assign the newly returned stack back to `stack`.

E.g. replace

```
stack.push(node);
```

with

```
stack = stack.push(node);
```